# Django Admin add/change disable a field based on previews field choice

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

in my django admin project i have this model:

```
class m_pcontent(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('T', 'Text'),
        ('I', 'Image'),
    )

    p_id = models.ForeignKey(m_pages, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    p_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MY_CHOICES)
    p_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    p_images = models.ForeignKey(m_pimg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

and in my admin.py

```
class m_pcontentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('p_id', 'p_type', 'p_lang', 'p_dload', 'p_active')
    list_filter = ('p_id', 'p_type', 'p_lang')
    ordering = ('p_id', 'p_type')
    readonly_fields = [...]
```

i would to dinamically make readonly the p_content field or the p_images field based on what user choice in p_type fiels in ADD/change area (if chose Text p_images have to become readonly, otherwise if choose Image p_content have to become Readonly)

Someone can elp me?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
# You have to write get_readonly_fields in your admin class

def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        if obj.p_type=='T': # if user select 'T' for Text
            self.readonly_fields + ['p_images',]
        elif obj.p_type=='I': # if user select 'I' for Image
            self.readonly_fields + ['p_content',]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks i have this error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'p_type'

Comment: obj is None during the object creation, but set to the object being edited during an edit. So, need to put a condition if obj exist. I have also edited my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks i tryed but get: 'NoneType' object is not iterable